# How are the boundary conditions given in the SIMPLE algorithm on a forward staggered grid for a lid driven cavity flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, boundary-conditions, algorithms

I have a code given by my professor in which he applies the boundary conditions for the lid driven cavity flow. All the enforcement of boundary conditions I have seen elsewhere completely differ from what he has done. In this case, he has set the link coefficients of all neighbor cells to 0 and only the considered cell to 1 for all the boundary walls and only for the top wall he has given 1 for the source term. For example when solving the U-Momentum:

```
! set boundary conditions for coefficients in the equations
! south
    aw(:,1)=0.
    ae(:,1)=0.
    as(:,1)=0.
    an(:,1)=0.
    ap(:,1)=1.
    su(:,1)=0.
! west
    aw(1,:)=0.
    ae(1,:)=0.
    as(1,:)=0.
    an(1,:)=0.
    ap(1,:)=1.
    su(1,:)=0.
! north
    aw(:,iNyUNodes)=0.
    ae(:,iNyUNodes)=0.
    as(:,iNyUNodes)=0.
    an(:,iNyUNodes)=0.
    ap(:,iNyUNodes)=1.
    su(:,iNyUNodes)=1.

! east
    aw(iNxUNodes,:)=0.
    ae(iNxUNodes,:)=0.
    as(iNxUNodes,:)=0.
    an(iNxUNodes,:)=0.
    ap(iNxUNodes,:)=1.
    su(iNxUNodes,:)=0.
```

I have tried to understand why he has done this, but I'm not getting any intuition at all. I can send a link of the code if needed.
What I have tried so far:

1. Tried changing all the coefficients to 1, which diverges the solution.
2. Tried changing all coefficients to 1 except the corresponding wall, i.e. if south wall, as = 0. Also diverges the solution.
3. Tried using a small value for the source, which resulted in expected behavior of a symmetric contour for the u-velocity since for a small lid velocity, diffusion would dominate.

Comment: I imagine these terribly-named variables have some meaning (e.g., the second letter indicates west, east, south, north, ?, ?), but without seeing it in context, I doubt anyone can address this. Perhaps it might be better to simply ask the person who gave you this code?

Comment: @KyleKanos yes, this was the work of our professor who gave us this code for an assignment with no context. I have figured it out recently but as you said the question itself couldn't be answered without seeing the whole code and with more context. I'll probably remove the question.